# PHP Prevent xss

Tags: php, xss

Is `htmlentities` best solution to prevent XSS in PHP? Also I would like to allow simple tags like `b`, `i`, `a` and `img`. What would be the best solution to implement this? I did consider bbcode but found out if not implemented properly I too will have XSS problem. What should I do? Any good third-party library is welcome.

EDIT:

I just tried HTML Purifier and it failed on this case. [Just see this example](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5bAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.Linkify%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.PurifierLinkify.DocURL%5d=%23%25s&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp.Exceptions%5d=td%0D%0Ath&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5d=0&filter%5bAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5d=0&filter%5bNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5d=1&filter%5bCore.CollectErrors%5d=0&filter%5bNull_HTML.Allowed%5d=1&filter%5bNull_HTML.Doctype%5d=1&filter%5bHTML.TidyLevel%5d=medium&filter%5bURI.DisableExternalResources%5d=0&filter%5bNull_URI.Munge%5d=1&html=Inline+context+No+block+allowed+)

Comment: Take a look at this site [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) Then take a look at this site [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) I think those links are interesting, too: [http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/) and [http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-js/](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-js/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that, I would go for the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), and yes you can specify your whitelist tags there too.

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   **malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
>
>   secure yet permissive whitelist**,   it
>   will also make sure your documents are
>   standards compliant, something only
>   achievable with a    comprehensive
>   knowledge of W3C's specifications.

I know there are certain functions in PHP *language* for that but I would prefer a dedicated solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at custom markup languages like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (used by stackoverflow), [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), [textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) or similar [lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code (it allows for `<i>`, `<b>` and `<del>`):

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                            

$html = '<b>Inline <del>context <div>No block allowed <great going </div></del></b>';                                                                                          

function escapeEveryOther(&$v, $k) {                                                                                                                                           
    if($k % 2 == 0) {                                                                                                                                                          
        $v = htmlspecialchars($v);                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                              

$parts = preg_split('`(</?(?:b|i|del)>)`is', $html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);                                                                                             
array_walk($parts, 'escapeEveryOther');                                                                                                                                        

$html = implode('', $parts);
```

and then pass `$html` through [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to fix non matching tag openings and closings.